# How does git push work in the context of remotes/origin?

Tags: git

`git pull origin master` fetches data from the remote server into origin/master on local.  It then merges origin/master with master branch.

How does git push work in this context? Does it first update the commit ref in origin/master, then sends new objects along with ref in origin/master back to remote?

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question.

`git push`

> Updates remote refs using local refs, while sending objects necessary
>   to complete the given refs.

From [the git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR version: no, it's the other order.  Long complete answer below.

---

First, a few minor notes:

> `git pull origin master` fetches data from the remote server into origin/master on local. It then merges origin/master with master branch.

This is slightly wrong in a few technical aspects.  Since your question is about reference updates, these may be important, so let's run through this briefly.

The `pull` script first runs `fetch`, then either `merge` or `rebase` as directed.

The `fetch` step starts by phoning up the URL listed for `origin`, retrieves ref-names and SHA-1 pairings from the remote, and brings over any *objects* needed for the SHA-1 that goes with the name `master`.  That is, if the remote says `refs/heads/master` is `1234...feed` and your local git doesn't have `1234...feed`, it brings over `1234...feed` add to your local repository.  Your git can then inspect `1234...feed` for its parent IDs and tree; if those are missing, it can bring those over too.  This repeats (usually optimized: with smart protocols, like git:// or ssh://, there's a pass where their git just walks the commit graph and trees giving your git SHA-1s) until your git and their git reach some shared SHA-1, where your git stops needing objects from them.

The updated starting-point information (in this case, that your git brought over their `master` which was `1234...feed`) is stored in a file named `FETCH_HEAD` in your `.git` directory.

In newer versions of git (post 1.8.4 or so), your local git then *also* updates its own local copy of `origin/master`.  In older versions of git this update is omitted.  Obviously this matters if you have an older git.

Last, the merge (or rebase) happens using the information out of `FETCH_HEAD`, rather than `origin/master`.  If your git is fairly old, these may be different.  (Perhaps someday this whole `FETCH_HEAD` thing can go away, but probably not for a long time yet.)

> How does git push work in this context? Does it first update the commit ref in origin/master, then sends new objects along with ref in origin/master back to remote?

Let's note here that `push` is the counterpart to `fetch`, rather than to `pull`.  It's still not quite symmetric, but it's closer: `pull` is `fetch`-then-`merge/rebase`, and `push` never does anything like merge or rebase.

As with `fetch`, `push` begins by Internet-calling the URL listed in for the remote named `origin` (the "pushurl" if there is one, or the plain url otherwise).  It then has a slightly different conversation, though: it starts by sending (rather than retrieving) some SHA-1s and some reference names.  As before, the two gits then have to converse for a bit to find common SHA-1s, so that your git can send over only the commit objects, trees, and blobs that you have that they don't.

Once the commits (and any other objects) are on the remote, the remote then runs any git hooks to see whether to allow the update.  If there is no git hook, the default, non-`--force` "allow update" test for a branch name—for the case where your git sent over `cafe...dada` for `refs/heads/master`, for instance—is simply "would adjusting that reference as requested be a fast-forward operation".

If the remote allows the update, it then does the update and tells your git "I did it".  If not, it rejects the update and tells your git "I reject this update for <fill in the blank reason>".

**If your git sees that their git accepted the update,** that's the point where your git updates its own `origin/master`.